making a new table from the results of a for statement of selected columns
i am new to python and i would like to know how i could transfer a column to another table if after analysing its regression score value r2 is greater than a set value
here is a sample of my code
for column,value in X.items():
    value=value.values.reshape(-1,1)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(value, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 50)

    regression=LinearRegression()
    regression.fit(X_train,y_train)
    cutoff = 0.999    

    def line_eq(m,x,c):#making the equation of the line
        return (m*x + c)

# the code below moves the line equation and the required calculations into the function
    def line_val(val):
        v = val [:]
        line_val = np.sqrt(np.sum(((y-line_eq(value,*v))**2)))
        return line_val
  
    line = optimize.minimize(line_val,[1,-1])#,tol = 10e-30) 
    y_fit= line_eq(value,*line.x[:2]) #fitting the function to the parameters
    plt.plot(value,y_fit)
    R2 = regression.score(X_test,y_test)
# here the code is checking to make sure that the accuracy of the perdicton is high and collecting the column

    df_2=pd.read_csv('best_fit.csv') # pre-made table with column headers only
    if R2 >= cutoff:
        df_2 = df[X.column].copy()
            
    plt.scatter(value,y)
    plt.xlabel(column)
    plt.grid()

       
    plt.show()
    print(f'For {column}, \n Coefficient of determination is;{R2}')
    print('fitting parameters:\n Slope = ',line.x[:1],'\n Intercept = ',line.x[1:2])

but i get an error saying
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'column'

how can i copy a column and its data if its regression value is greater than my set point?
i have made a new table in the previous slide with the columns headers but failed to copy the values in the raws from the selected column meeting my R2 value

The error should be related with the following code:
if R2 >= cutoff:
    df_2 = df[X.column].copy()

As X is a dataframe but it doesn't have column attribute. Another problem is it doesn't need to load df_2 inside a for-loop, it will have very bad performance.
Revised code:

df_2 = pd.read_csv('best_fit.csv') # put it outside of for-loop

for column,value in X.items():
    # your origin code
    ... 

    if R2 >= cutoff:
        df_2[column] = X[column].copy()

    # your origin code
    ... 



thanks for the reply @linpingta
You see,
I opened a data frame [csv table] with many columns and I grouped the columns into x and y
the columns in x are under the Variable X.
for regression, i am comparing all the columns in X with the column of y and containing the R2 value
after this, i have set the cut off value for R2 and if the result is above that,
i would like to have the column copied into a new table called 'Best_fit.csv'
my problem is how to get the column and its values to shift to the new table when it meets the cutoff value condition
this is what i don't know to code
